# How to save RequestsCookieJar structure into file in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to handle numerous `requests.Session()` in just one session. So I need to store and retrieve cookies.

I know I can do it using copy and update like:

```
c = requests.Session()
#login....

#store cookies
cook1=c.cookies.copy()
c.cookies.clear()

#restore
c.cookies.update(cook1)
```

What is the problem?

I don't know how to store variable `cook1` into a file also retrieve from a file. Also, I need to store a list of items into a file like `[cook1, cook2, ...]`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store cookie details in a list and write to a file

```
import pprint

cke_lst = []
for cookie in c.cookies:
    cke_lst.append([cookie.name,cookie.value,cookie.domain])

data = pprint.pformat(cke_lst)

with open('cookies.py','w') as f:
    f.write('ckes = '+data)
```

To update cookies from file

```
from cookies import ckes

for cke in ckes:
    c.cookies.set(cke[0],cke[1],domain=cke[2])
```